# How to enable back to previous page in a app with Navigation Drawer and webview

Tags: java, android, webview, navigation-drawer, back

I created an android app with android studio that has a navigation drawer (with fragments) and webview but when I am opening pages and I click the back button it closes the app and does not go back to the previous page.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
} else {
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

I created an android app with android studio that has a navigation drawer (with fragments) and webview but when I am opening pages and I click the back button it closes the app and does not go back to the previous page. I want the app to be able to go back to previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (webView.canGoBack()) {
      webView.goBack();
   } else {
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

You can add your logic, but key methods is `webView.canGoBack()` and `webVeiw.goBack()`

Comment: I tried but webView it's red and display the message: Cannot resolve symbol 'webView'

Comment: Can you paste the code? Maybe you use mWebView variable?

Comment: Said I used the exact same code: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

Comment: I understand, but can you copy line where you defined your webView?

Comment: I don't think I have defined. How do I define?

Comment: How do I define? I forgot to mention, I am using fragments with the navigation drawer.